# How to create query to fetch all iOS Developers in my city?

Tags: support, community-data

Currently I am doing:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Reputation DESC) AS Rank,
Id AS [User Link], Reputation
FROM Users
WHERE LOWER(Location) LIKE '%krak%' AND LOWER(AboutMe) LIKE '%ios%' AND Reputation > 10
ORDER BY Reputation DESC;
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/893925/top-so-ios-users-in-krakow

All ios developers are recognized by most used tag: xcode, ios or swift. How can I fetch that info?;)

**EDIT:**

> @Rene It is not duplicated question, because the question ypu refer to is about SPECIFIC TAG. In my question I need to find users who have the most popular tags either xcode, either ios or swift.

Comment: Join with the posts table (questions and their answers) and restrict the set on the value in the `tags` field of questions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am not as good in creating queries with JOINs;)

Comment: I get that SQL Joins might be hard to grasp but adding two `OR` clauses to a where should be doable. The duplicate is fine.